# error NU1102: Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization with version (>= 2.2.0)

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, .net-core-sdk

In my build pipeline, I have a step as follows:

[image]

SDK version I'm using in global.json is 3.1.201". With this, when I try to create a build, I get the following error:

```
error NU1102: Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization with version (>= 2.2.0)
error NU1102:   - Found 9 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [ Nearest version: 1.1.3 ]
```

I don't know if this is related sdk version. Can someone help with fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this step and also adding the step NUGET Installer before and switching from visual_studio 2017 to windows 2019 as the build agent solved the problem for me.

Strangely when creating a new pipeline from template "Azure function" the Nuget Restore step is missing...

Answer (score 1):

Can you add step to restore nuget packages. I don't see this one on attached screen.

Comment: I get this error on adding restore nuget task: error : Version 3.1.201 of the .NET Core SDK requires at least version 16.3.0 of MSBuild. The current available version of MSBuild is 15.9.21.664. Change the .NET Core SDK specified in global.json to an older version that requires the MSBuild version currently available.